# Get from the rows highest result

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the highest result from all rows in a colum, for example.
Column

```
food
drink
food
food
food
dring
food
chicken
else
chicken
```

I i want to get that rows that have the highest numbers, that are mostly used like i my way food, so how to get that food ? I want to check all the rows, and get the most used one .

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stackoverflow community. Please take a look at the other questions on this website and try to format your question so it will fit the community. Currently the question gives only few information and it's very likely that this question is already answered somewhere in the community. Why not search for it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT foodName FROM tbl GROUP BY foodName ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: You could also consider adding a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: Something else ? this is returning wrong result, it is returning the number of different results in all rows in a column i want to return the most uset result in column